# disable dropdown menu in mobile version

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

i am working on a wordpress theme where i am facing an issue of having submenu display on mouse hover in mobile versions. what i basically want achieve is to stop display of sub menu in mobile version even on hover as well as on click it should not be visible at any cost in mobile. i can do that through jquery and also through css but in css it will also effect the menu on normal display in bigger screens other then mobiles and through jquery i tried but unfortunately all in vain. below is the code for jquery and i also prefer it on jquery so need help from all you guys

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {

var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width(); //retrieve current window width
var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height(); //retrieve current window height
if(windowWidth < 1024){

   jQuery('ul.nav li.dropdown a').click(function (){
   jQuery($this).find('ul.dropdown-menu').css("display" , "none !important");

   });
 }
});
```

i handle it through many ways but this is the latest one and i also know i am not good at jquery. below is the link to the website where you can see same thing when you hover on services http://test.nerdalert.com/ and also you guys can check the mobile version on http://www.responsinator.com/?url=test.nerdalert.com%2F

Answer (score 0):

Jquery

```
(function( $ ) {  
    var mobile = $.browser.mobile;              
    if(!mobile) {                                             

    Your Code  Here     

    }                  }(jQuery);
```

Or CSS Which loads quicker.

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) { .What You Are Hiding Here { display: none; } }
```